# PHP File Download stops

Tags: php, download

I am writing a basic license-validated PHP download script. The target file is about 50MB, and it works for some. Others can't finish it, sometimes retrying it works.

Here is the script:

```
$method = $_GET['method'];
    if($method == "webdownload") {
        $airlineid = $_GET['airline'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM airlines WHERE airlineid='$airlineid'";   
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if($row['licensekey'] == "")
            die("Invalid airline id");

        $filename = $row['code'].'_installer.exe';
        $file_path = '../resources/application/files/'.$row['airlineid'].'/'.$row['clientversion'].'/application_installer.exe';
        if($row['licensestate'] != "OK")
            die("The license associated with this downloaded has been deauthorized.");

        if(!is_file($file_path))
            die("The file associated with this version for this airline appears to be invalid.");
        //download code here - it runs once only, if refreshed it will not allow it.                

        header('Content-type: application/exe');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
        header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file_path));
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");    

        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');   

        //header('X-Sendfile: '.$file_path); I tried this - it had no effect and I want the portability.

        $file = @fopen($file_path,"rb");
        while(!feof($file)) {           
            $buffer = fread($file, 1024 * 8);
            print($buffer);
            flush();            
        }
        close($file);       
    }
```

EDIT: Upon advice, I discovered that the script, among others, is highly vulnerable to SQL injection. I have replaced direct variable-SQL expressions with the use of this function:

```
        function secure_string($raw) {
    $sid = strtolower($raw);
    $sid = str_replace("'","_SINGLE_QUOTE", $sid);
    $sid = str_replace('"','_DOUBLE_QUOTE', $sid);


    $cmd[0] = "insert";
    $cmd[1] = "select";
    $cmd[2] = "union";
    $cmd[3] = "delete";
    $cmd[4] = "modify";
    $cmd[5] = "replace";
    $cmd[6] = "update";
    $cmd[7] = "create";
    $cmd[8] = "alter";


    for($index = 0; $index <= 8; $index++) {
        $sid = str_replace($cmd[$index],"_SQL_COMMAND", $sid);
    }

    return $sid;        
}
```

Is that sufficient to block SQL-injection?

EDIT2: I have used this function in conjunction with a PDO prepare functions to eliminate this exploit. Thanks 100x for letting me learn this lesson without disastrous results.

Comment: Quick question, what happens when I type `' or 1 = 1` as the airline query string parameter?

Comment: Immediately, nothing. However, I looked it up, and when using ' or '1'='1 (as it's written there) as the parameter, it downloaded the first file in the list. I had a mini-heart attack. I guess I'll be spending tomorrow covering my SQL injection vulnerabilities. Good catch, thanks.

Comment: I missed the `--` from the end of my example sql injection and by the time I noticed I couldn't edit my comment. I would suggest you take a look at PDO and parameterised queries as an easy way to prevent such attacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) is a function that puts the entire file into the buffer in one go. Will probably prevent PHP from timing out. Use it instead of the `fopen()` and `print()` loop you have at the bottom.

Another solution is to see if you server has [`mod_x_sendfile`](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) as this takes the downloading out of PHP and into apache internals.

Edit: I notice you say you've tried sendfile. Might be a better option if you can get it working.